# Time Complexity in Python - Big O notation

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

The output of my program look like:

```
[[1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000],
[437, 680, 917, 1115, 1476, 1668, 1912]]
```

It's two-dimensional array created via Numpy Library. In the first row is number of N which I pass to the function, and the second row is time-measurment of this function in micro-seconds (e.g. N=1000 time=437, N=1500 time=680).

Is there any simple way to determine which is the complexity of this function? I know I can paint a plot and just see this but my app needs to give me just the answer (Your function is (probably, of course) O(n) or O(n log n) or O(n^2)).

O(n) seems to be preety obvious - I just need to divide N/t for all array and check if it is constant, but I have no idea how to check another two?

Comment: You may have better luck if you ask this question at https://cs.stackexchange.com/, as it really has nothing to do with programming, but with computer science.

Answer (score 1):

One can do all sorts of fancy *curve fitting* and *model evaluation* with `sklearn`. But for a simple approach, measuring the variance of the logarithm of the thing that's expected to be constant will do. That is,

1. Take the ratio such as T/N, or T/(N*log(N)), or T/N**2. We'd like this to be constant.
2. Take the logarithm of that ratio, to remove the effects of scaling.
3. Compute the variance across the data points, with `np.var`. The model with the smallest variance wins.

For your example:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000])
t = np.array([437, 680, 917, 1115, 1476, 1668, 1912])
print(np.var(np.log(t/n)))              # 0.001545...
print(np.var(np.log(t/(n*np.log(n)))))  # 0.001348...
print(np.var(np.log(t/(n**2))))         # 0.18049...
```

So it's definitely not quadratic. The `N*log(N)` is a slightly better fit than linear. (Trying a few other things, it seems `N*sqrt(log(N))` is best.)